# Travelling from Afghanistan to Guatemala

Tags: schengen, transit, morocco, afghan-citizens, guatemala

I have been invited to an official training in Guatemala, so now I plan to go to Guatemala from Afghanistan and I will use the Morroco and Madrid airport as transit countries. So, please let me know whether I need Schengen Transit Visa or not?

Comment: What about Morroco @Traveller?

Comment: @British Sam Good point - although the OP asked about Schengen specifically

Comment: @traveller, true!

Answer (score 5):

Afghan citizens need a visa to enter Guatemala.

Per Timatic, https://www.timaticweb2.com transiting Morocco without a visa is possible for:

- Passengers transiting through Casablanca (CMN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
- Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Transiting Spain without a visa is possible for:

- Nationals of Afghanistan transiting through Barcelona (BCN) or Madrid (MAD) and arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State.

  They must:

  - have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Republic of Ireland, Japan, Romania, USA or United Kingdom, and
  - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
  - have documents required for the next destination.
- Otherwise, see: [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)